# How to trigger global function within a context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, contextmenu

I have a [table](https://datatables.net/) that's populated by a list of documents (from a JSON file), and clicking on a checkbox adds that particular document to a favorites list.

I created a custom context menu with three options. **I'm trying to make it so that someone clicks on one of the options ("Add to Favorites") and it does the same as what I described above.** Simply put, I don't know how to trigger the function because it's outside the scope of the original favorites function. I tried grouping the favorites functionality in its own function and referencing it, but something was off with my syntax (or I was way off and not headed in the right direction?). Any thoughts?

#### JS add favorites functionality:

```
function faveFunc(evt) {
  const $table = $("#km-table-id")

  let table = $table.DataTable();
  let favesArr = [];

      let data = table.row(this.parentNode).data(),
      checked = $(this).is(":checked"),
      dataIndex = favesArr.indexOf(data);
      if (checked) {
        if (dataIndex === -1) {
          favesArr.push(data); // add item
        }
      } else {
        if (dataIndex > -1) {
          favesArr.splice(dataIndex, 1); // remove item
        }
      }  


      // - Appending selected faves to div - //

      ($(".populate-faves").empty()); // removes all previous entries
      for (var i = 0; i < favesArr.length; i++) {
        $(".populate-faves").append(JSON.stringify(favesArr[i].Titles) + '<br/><br/>').addClass("faved-doc");  
      }


    }; // ------------ faveFunc

    $("#km-table-id.checkbox-class, [data-action='add']").on("click", faveFunc)


  console.log(faveFunc)
```

#### Context menu:

```
  ///// Show menu /////
  $(document).on("contextmenu", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    $(".custom-menu")
    .show()
    .css({ top: evt.pageY, left: evt.pageX });

    ///// Close menu /////
    $(document).on("mousedown", function(evt) {
      if (!$(evt.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
      }
    })
  });
```

#### HTML snippet:

```
<ul class="custom-menu">
  <li data-action="open">Open Document</li>
  <li data-action="add" oncontextmenu="()">Set As Favorite</li>
  <li data-action="email"><a href="mailto:?subject=subject">Email Document</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**`faveFunc` only sets a listener**

Let's look at `faveFunc`:

```
function faveFunc() {
    let addFave = $table.on("click", ".checkbox-class", function(e) {
        // ...
    })
}
```

When you call `faveFunc`, all it does is set a "click" listener. It doesn't actually *execute* the click listener.

**`document` isn't what you think**

Regarding `$(document).on("contextmenu")` and `$(document).on("click")`: `document` is a global variable on webpages that refers to the webpage itself. It does not refer to any of the content of the webpage. These events will fire when you click or right-click anywhere on the page.

**Be consistent in how you set event listeners.**

You are currently doing this three different ways:

- `$(selector).on("click")`
- `$(selector).click()`
- `$(selector).on("click", filter)`

Pick one. Personally, I prefer `$(selector).on("click")`.

**Make the event handler into a named function**

Instead of this:

```
function faveFunc() {
    let addFave = $table.on("click", ".checkbox-class", function(e) {
        // ...
    })
}
```

...I would do this:

```
function faveFunc(e){
    // ...
}
$("#km-table-id.checkbox-class").on("click", faveFunc)
```

This way, you can re-use the `faveFunc` event handler:

```
function faveFunc(e){
    // ...
}
$("#km-table-id.checkbox-class").on("click", faveFunc)
$("[data-action='add']").on("click", faveFunc)
```

You can also combine those into one function since jQuery supports the CSS `,`:

```
$("#km-table-id.checkbox-class, [data-action='add']").on("click", faveFunc)
```

Comment: So, is addFave() what should be reused because it executes the click?

Comment: I'm having trouble answering further because it's still not clear to me exactly what you want to happen. Can you write it out as a series of steps? Something like: 1. The user right-clicks. 2. A context menu opens, displaying a list of documents. 3. The user clicks on a document. 4. The document is added to their list of favorites.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I want to happen. What works: Right clicking on table cell and the context menu opening. What I want to implement: User selecting on "Add to Favorites", then that document is added to the list. I'll update the body of my question for clarity.

Comment: One thing to address first, regarding `$(document).on("contextmenu")` and `$(document).on("click")`: `document` is a global variable on webpages that refers to the webpage itself. It does not refer to any of the content of the webpage. These events will fire when you click or right-click anywhere on the page.

Comment: I didn't notice that, but you're definitely right. I made it so that right clicking only works on the table. Quick question: Can I attach the `data-action` for "Add to Favorites" to the original `addFave` line, so that both can be used? I'll provide a separate update to my code above.

Comment: I made the edits you suggested (I'm liking the elegance of the named function and the single line at the end). However, faveFunc() only shows up in the console and is not displaying the data to the browser. The checkboxed favorites functionality also stopped working. Any thoughts? [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/b527p0wy/) a fiddle.

Comment: Looks like jQuery hasn't been added to that fiddle. It also doesn't have access to `DataTable`. Can you just update your code above? No need to keep your old code; you can overwrite it.